# Creating dynamically component by variable value - Java

Tags: java, user-interface, dynamic, components, jtextfield

I have a gui where I can enter the value (`JTextField` - the value of new components is declared) and when I click on `JButton` I will get below new components (`JTextField`).

I try:

```
JButton button = new JButton("Do it");
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        for(int i=0;i<Integer.parseInt(textField.getText());i++){       
        add(new JTextField());
            validate();
            repaint();
        }
    }
});
```

How should I write code for geting new components?

my method:

```
public static void newComp(String value)
    {
        for(int i=0;i<Integer.parseInt(value);i++)
        {       
            contentPane.add(new JTextField());
            contentPane.revalidate();
            contentPane.repaint();
    }
```

Comment: Make a "public static void" method in your GUI/JFrame, which takes the string you use (textField.getText()) as a parameter. Then create your for-loop and textfields in that method. Remember, this method will be static, so you can't use parameters outside the method, except those that you give it as parameters.

It might be a good idea, to position and customize the textfields before adding them. Otherwise they'll all be on top of eachother. And instead of alidate(); (I'm sure it's a typo), try revalidate();

Comment: Another idea could be, if you have a maximum amount of available textfields, to create them at the beginning, and setVisible(false); on them. Then you can make them visible when you need them.

Comment: i created method , look at my first post, Whats i did wrong? How to set position textfields when the components is not create?

Comment: Instead of doing contentPane.add(new JTextField()), just create a new variable in your for-loop, like JTextField temp = new JTextField(); and set the position on temp, then add it to the contentpane. If you want them to be spawned underneath each other, do something like temp.setPosition(someStartPositionX, someStartPositionY + (i*20));

Answer (score 0):

I think its better if you create an ArrayList and add the new components to it. Then create a method initComponents() where you initializes all the components in it including the new components from the ArrayList. Then create another method like the following:

```
void refresh() {
    contentPane.removeAll();
    button.clear();
    textField.clear();
    initComponents();
    contentPane.revalidate();
    contentPane.repaint();
}
```

This way you are removing everything from the panel and then dynamically you are adding the new components. And don't forget to re-add the listeners.